# Google App Engine url_rewrite php app

Tags: php, google-app-engine, url-rewriting, yaml

Totally new to GAE and want to test my php site using GAE locally.
I've all setup and have my site running on localhost:8080 with GAE.

The php site have been running with nginx with the following config

```
# First attempt to serve request as file, then
# as directory, then fall back to index.html
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
```

Where the urls like localhost/dynamic-url have been forwarded to the php app like index.php?q=dynamic-url.

How can i make this happen with GAE? Can i make this happend w/o touching the php files?

This is my yaml file

```
application: gallerysite
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /img
  static_dir: img

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the section on "Clean URLs" in Jimmys excellent post about standing up drupal on GAE for a way to write a simple router script.

http://blog.boombatower.com/drupal-google-app-engine